# Chromebook not booting Ubuntu versions (Bay Trail) (Acer CB3-531)

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, chromebook

I have a Chromebook, and have successfully installed Gallium OS. (yes I known, also Ubuntu based) this is the only version that will boot up the OS correctly Out of the Box.

All other Ubuntu version that I tried (Ubuntu, Ubuntu Mate, Ubuntu Budgie) are having the same issue after installing. They all give the GRUB command line.

When I go into the BIOS, I can browse for a EFI file, and when I start the one located in `EFI/Ubuntu/Grubx64.efi` it will start the OS.
But I do not want to do this manually.

How I can get get this EFI / Grub issue to work and Ubuntu to boot and work on my Chromebook?

- harddrive where it is installed on MMCBLK0.
- MMCBLK0p1 is EFI (Fat32) (boot flag set).
- MMCBLK0p2 is ext4.
- there is 2048kb space free in the front of all partitions.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: Here is my export of the boot repair util.
hope you can help out.
https://paste2.org/tBvnKCcD

Comment: Gallium OS is not Ubuntu (or one of its official flavours) and off topic on Ask *Ubuntu*. We don't know how other Linux distributions work in detail – especially with something as intricate as the boot procedure on Chromebooks. You can ask questions about any Linux distribution over on [Unix.SE].

Comment: Dear David, as this is not about galliumOS, but about all other ubuntu versions. I gave an example of GalliumOS that is based on Ubuntu...

But hopefully, you can give me a solution, as i tried Fedora, and Fedora is also working out of the box, but I REALY want an ubuntu based distro to work.....

Comment: Your question appears to be specifically how Gallium OS is able to boot on your Chromebook which is off topic on Ask *Ubuntu*. If you want to know how to boot *Ubuntu* on your Chromebook please [edit] your question to request just that and remove any (secondary) questions that may be off topic. Thanks.

Comment: As you accepted an answer that describes how to boot *Ubuntu* I'll take the liberty to remove the part of your question that is about Gallium OS. This would render your question on topic and I'll vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Boot Repair output is incomplete because that utility does not yet properly support eMMC and similar advanced SSD types, which show up in Linux with the `/dev/mmcblk0` and related filenames rather than the traditional `/dev/sda`-style filenames. Thus, I'm still in the dark about some significant factors, such as exactly what EFI programs (with `.efi` extensions) are stored on the ESP (`/boot/efi` in Ubuntu).

That said, there is one very important clue about the cause of the problem in your Boot Info summary:

```
=================== efibootmgr -v
Timeout: 3 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001
Boot0000* EFI eMMC Device   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17,0x0)/Msg(29,00)/Ctrl(0x0)
Boot0001* EFI Internal Shell MemoryMapped(11,0x830000,0xc0ffff)/FvFile(c57ad6b7-0515-40a8-9d21-551652854e37)
```

This shows *no `ubuntu` entry.* Normally, an installed Ubuntu will include an entry that points to `EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi`; however, this NVRAM entry is missing from your system. (The `efibootmgr` utility displays and manipulates the contents of the computer's NVRAM-based EFI boot manager entries.) Instead, the computer is booting the `EFI eMMC Device` by default. This is *probably* booting the `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` file, which I'm guessing is an incomplete or incorrect GRUB entry. There are at least three ways to fix this problem:

- **Create a proper NVRAM entry** -- This *should have* been done by the Ubuntu installer, so it's possible that your computer's firmware is defective and is forgetting properly-created entries. OTOH, it's also possible that there was a problem during Ubuntu installation that prevented the installer from creating this entry. Thus, it's worth trying to do it manually. To do so, type `sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/mmcblk0 -p 1 -l \\EFI\\ubuntu\\shimx64.efi -L ubuntu`. If you then type `sudo efibootmgr -v`, you should see the new `ubuntu` entry, and when you reboot, it should boot into GRUB and show you a menu. If you get the same old behavior, and if `sudo efibootmgr -v` after you use your workaround to boot shows that the `ubuntu` entry has disappeared, then your firmware (or perhaps NVRAM hardware) is definitely defective. It might be worth looking for a firmware update from the manufacturer and trying again, or even returning the computer to the store for a refund if you're within the return period.
- **Use the `fbx64.efi` program** -- This program is installed in some recent Ubuntu installations, but it doesn't do anything useful the way it's installed. To make it useful, follow these steps:

  1. Type `sudo mv /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT-backup` to backup the existing `EFI/BOOT` directory on the ESP.
  2. Type `sudo mkdir /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT` to create a new fallback directory on the ESP.
  3. Type `sudo cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` to copy Shim from the `EFI/ubuntu` directory on the ESP to `EFI/BOOT`, using the fallback filename (`bootx64.efi`) in its new location.
  4. Type `sudo cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/fbx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT` to copy `fbx64.efi` to the fallback directory (`EFI/BOOT`) on the ESP.
  5. Create a text file called `boot.txt` in your home directory. It should be a single line that reads `grubx64.efi,ubuntu,,This is the boot entry for ubuntu`.
  6. Type `sudo iconv -t UCS-2 < ~/boot.txt > ~/BOOT.CSV`. This converts the file you created into a form that the `fbx64.efi` file can read
  7. Type `sudo cp ~/BOOT.CSV /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` to copy `BOOT.CSV` to the `EFI/ubuntu` directory on the ESP.

  The point of this procedure is that the `fbx64.efi` program, when run, scans every subdirectory of `EFI` on the ESP looking for files called `BOOT.CSV`. If found, it uses those files to regenerate an NVRAM entry for the boot loader(s) described in the `BOOT.CSV` file. When it's done, the first entry in the new boot order is run. Thus, if `fbx64.efi` is run as the fallback boot loader (which it will be when copied as in steps #1-4), and if you create a suitable `BOOT.CSV` file, Ubuntu's GRUB should launch from its normal location even if your NVRAM entries are routinely lost. This isn't as good as having a working EFI boot manager, but it's better than using the next option, with the caveat that this procedure is more tedious than the next one. One important caveat is that if the ESP has *other* `BOOT.CSV` files, one of them might end up first in the boot order, which could lead the process astray. Thus, if you have problems, you may want to search for such files and delete or rename them if you think they may be causing problems.
- **Use the fallback filename** -- If the preceding approaches don't work, you can copy the working GRUB to get it to work as follows:

  1. Type `sudo mv /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT-backup` to backup the existing `EFI/BOOT` directory on the ESP.
  2. Type `sudo cp -r /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT` to put the working Ubuntu boot loader in the `EFI/BOOT` directory.
  3. Type `sudo mv /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/shimx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` to rename Shim to the fallback filename so that it will launch by default.

  There is a danger in this third approach: If my diagnosis is wrong, or if `shimx64.efi` is missing or defective in the ESP's `EFI/ubuntu` directory, then this procedure will leave the computer unbootable. In this case, you'll need to use an emergency system to reverse that procedure to restore the system to its current semi-working state. Also, the third approach will leave you running the currently-installed Shim and GRUB forever, unless you intervene manually; you will *not* get updates installed through the Ubuntu package manager. For these reasons, getting the NVRAM entries in order via the first approach is the preferable solution -- but given the nature of your problem, I'm not hopeful that this will be possible.

If you're experimenting with different distributions, be aware that each installation is likely to require its own `grub.cfg` file in the same directory as Shim and GRUB (`EFI/ubuntu` or `EFI/BOOT` on the ESP). Thus, at a minimum, you'll need to move `grub.cfg` if you install a new distribution if you use the third fix. You may need to completely redo that third fix if you install an unrelated distribution.

Comment: great solution! followed it step by step, seems that option 2 was the solution for me.
when I rebooted after I implemented solution 2, i got an error that he was missing grubx64.efi, copied this over from /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu to /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT
also shimx64.efi was copied over. Now the Chromebook is booting normal, without selecting an EFI file in the Bios.

Comment: Tested it also out with UBUNTU, and yes, it is the SAME SOLUTION